# Invalid data type conversion in a namespace

Tags: c++, types, namespaces

In my project, i have simple_xxxx.c which is not system thread safe version, hence to create a system thread equivalent, i have created sys_xxxx.cpp; where the entire C code is captured inside a namespace called MyNameSpace. In the file I'm not including simple_xxxx.h to risk the confusion on compilation, but sys_xxxx.h is included to get the declarations for my .cpp file. While doing so, i get compilation error for the below enum, which gets confused for int, even  thought it is declared inside the namespace.

Any suggestion is most welcome for this please.

```
// xxxx.h

namespace MyNameSpace {

typedef enum {
  FormatFlags_LeftAlign   = (1 << 0), // 1
  FormatFlags_SignPrefix  = (1 << 1), // 2
  FormatFlags_SpacePrefix = (1 << 2), // 4
  FormatFlags_ZeroPad     = (1 << 3), // 8
  FormatFlags_Format      = (1 << 4)  // 16
} FormatFlags;


bool string_AppendFormatted(UnicodeString_s*, UnicodeString_s*, void*);

}


///xxxx.cpp

namespace MyNameSpace {

bool string_AppendFormatted(UnicodeString_s*, UnicodeString_s*, void*)
{
      FormatFlags eFlags = (FormatFlags)0;

            case '-':
4086:         eFlags |= FormatFlags_LeftAlign;
              break;
            case '+':
4089:         eFlags |= FormatFlags_SignPrefix;
              break;
            case '0':
4092:         eFlags |= FormatFlags_ZeroPad;
              break;
} // method

} // namespace


xxxx.cpp: In function 'bool MyNameSpace::string_AppendFormatted(MyNameSpace::UnicodeString_s*, MyNameSpace::UnicodeString_s*, void*)':
xxxx.cpp:4086: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'MyNameSpace::FormatFlags'
xxxx.cpp:4089: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'MyNameSpace::FormatFlags'
xxxx.cpp:4092: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'MyNameSpace::FormatFlags'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing the follow allows me to solve the issue.
eFlags = (FormatFlags)(eFlags | FormatFlags_LeftAlign);

If i declare the enum type as int; it cause further issue to my code below (not shown here).

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `enum` in C++, use an `int` to store your flags. Also, you can declare the enum as `enum FormatFlags{ /* values */ };`, the `typedef` is only needed for C.

Comment: Just learnt about the CPP enum handling; which is slightly different from the way C does. Anyway my compilation error is gone and I'm happy. Thanks for your answer.

eFlags |= FormatFlags_LeftAlign;

replaced with 

eFlags = (FormatFlags)(eFlags | FormatFlags_LeftAlign);

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
FormatFlags eFlags = (FormatFlags)0;
```

with

```
int eFlags = 0;
```

As the error message says, you cannot cast a combination of enums, which is an `int`, back to an enum (notice that the values for these combinations are not defined in your enum definition).

Comment: Converting FormatFlags to int cause other statements where the eFlags are supplied to functions are throwing error. Here is my fix for the issue. Thanks for your answer anyway.                   eFlags = (FormatFlags)(eFlags | FormatFlags_LeftAlign);

Comment: It's up to you, I had no visibility on the rest of the code though...Consider accepting the other answer when the timer let you do it, since it matched your need.